# Вывод в таблицу с автосоздаваемыми столбцами

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, datagrid

Здравствуйте. Имеется следующая структура базы данных:

### [image: Структура БД]

В таблице PARALLEL хранятся классы, а в таблице BASIC_CURRICULUM - часы по учебному плану для них.

В проекте на WPF я пытаюсь разработать форму, позволяющую редактировать часы в учебном плане, но все упирается в то, что я никак не могу вывести классы как столбцы в таблице. В XAML-е приходится заранее прописывать столбцы для DataGrid-а. А в самом приложении используется модель ADO.NET EDM, поэтому все запросы написаны на Linq. Вот примерно так я хочу, чтобы данные отображались в таблице для редактирования:

### [image: Структура БД]

Как сделать так, чтобы столбцы в таблице определялись в зависимости от содержания таблицы PARALLEL?

**UPD**: В данный момент код разметки таблицы выглядит следующим образом (таблица на скриншоте взята из другого проекта):

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="AcademicPlanGrid" Language="ru-RU" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionChanged="AcademicPlanGrid_SelectionChanged" RowEditEnding="AcademicPlanGrid_RowEditEnding" PreviewKeyDown="AcademicPlanGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
                  AddingNewItem="AcademicPlanGrid_AddingNewItem" BeginningEdit="AcademicPlanGrid_BeginningEdit">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Предмет" Binding="{Binding Path=SUBJECT_NAME, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR1, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR2, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="3" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR3, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="4" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR4, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="5" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR5, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="6" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR6, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="7" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR7, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="8" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR8, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="9" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR9, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="10" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR10, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="11" Binding="{Binding Path=PAR11, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Для ее заполнения пришлось создать промежуточный класс AcademicPlan. Данные из LINQ-запросов в него конвертируются с помощью цикла, что я считаю костылем.

```
    private class AcademicPlan
    {
        public int SUBJECT_ID { get; set; }

        public string SUBJECT_NAME { get; set; }

        public int? PAR1 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR2 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR3 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR4 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR5 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR6 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR7 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR8 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR9 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR10 { get; set; }

        public int? PAR11 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код  view

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы хотите взглянуть на код разметки таблицы. Обновил свое сообщение выше. Прописывал в нем столбцы вручную, потому что так привычнее было осуществлять привязку. Но суть моей проблемы заключается в том, что я вполне могу сделать так, чтобы столбцы добавлялись автоматически по примеру отсюда: [http://howtucode.com/programmatically-add-column-amp-rows-to-wpf-datagrid-51255.html]. Но я все еще не знаю как в этом случае осуществить привязку, а самое главное - как составить LINQ-запрос, в котором столбцы определялись бы содержанием таблицы.

Comment: Чем ваш вариант с промежуточным классом вас не устраивает? Это *нормальный правильный* вариант. Классы модели не ставят перед собой цели быть удобными для привязки и не должны этого делать. Одна и та же модель может работать как в WPF, так и в консольном приложении или в веб-приложении. Берите свою модель как она есть, пишите VM таким образом, чтобы к ней было удобно привязываться в GUI. Остается просто конвертировать M в VM при чтении из базы и назад при сохранении.

Comment: А у вас всегда 11 столбцов? Если да, тогда да, предложение Андрея релевантно

Comment: хм, можно ведь названия хранить в RowHeader а таблицу привязывать через [DataGrid2d](https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D) например

Comment: @АндрейNOP, тогда вопрос состоит в том, что можно ли конвертацию реализовать эту конвертацию через LINQ-запрос или более удобный цикл - мой сейчас не самый лучший.

Comment: @AntonShakalo, сейчас да, но в будущем в рамках этого же проекта всплывет таблица, в которой будет не фиксированное число столбцов. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать как в этом случае решить задачу, прежде чем с ней снова столкнуться.

Comment: @FoggyFinder а вот про это не знал. Надо разобраться как там можно реализовать редактирование данных.

Comment: Если решить DataGrid2D использовать то можете смело задавать вопросы в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) попробую ответить